# Holdout set for image task

Tags: cross-validation, maximum-likelihood, model-selection, image-processing, out-of-sample

I need to validate whether one or two templates/shapes are present in an image.
Fitting two templates has a better maximum likelihood then fitting one template which is a clear symptom of overfitting. What I would like to do is set aside some test set and then check whether one template or two templates generalise better.

When working with iid data items in regression or classification tasks, we can leave some data at side to use for testing and this can help with model selection. 
(Cross-validation is of course is also an alternative option to keeping a holdout set.)

My question is: can I do something similar for my template problem? I.e. could I randomly  leave some pixels out of training and use them to test whether one template or two templates generalise better? Somehow this doesn't sit well with me as in contrast to the regression/classification problem, here the pixels are not exactly iid (that is neighbouring pixels must be correlated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say in image analysis the cases to set aside are *images* not *pixels*.

This would apply to cross validation as well as to hold out.

---

Update: 
From what you explain about your application, you can and should indeed test on images that were not used for deriving the shape fitting algorithm (i.e. a new set of images). You can then count how many cars were correctly recognized, and how many false positives or false negatives you have.
So this is generalization to unknown images.

---

Testing left-out pixels: Not only are neighbour pixels not independent but also very basic properties of your image change. Imagine a kind of 4-fold cross validation scheme where you keep every 2nd column and every 2nd row for testing. This corresponds to an image at half the resolution compared to the original image. What you would test with this hold out pixels approach is generalization to (ruggedness agains) lower resolution images.
I.e. this may make sense in certain situations, but you'll measure a completely different performance characteristic.

Comment: I agree with this. But what if every image is a separate problem? What I mean is that you don't have two independent images of the same thing. In the case I describe, every image may have 1 or 2 templates present and positioned different in different locations.

Comment: Maybe I didn't properly understand your question then. Please explain your application so that someone who does not know at all what you are doing understands what is going on.

Comment: Indeed I may not have been clear enough. Say you have a model for a car template. This car template roughly captures what a car looks like in a (noisy) image. Some images depict one car, others two. Given an image, you want to decide how many cars are depicted. To do this you fit the car-templates. So you fit one template and measure the log-likelihood. Then you fit two templates and measure again the log-likelihood. Usually, the two-template solution will exhibit a higher log-likelihood even for pictures with one depicted car because it overfits. How to measure generalisation in this case?

Comment: You are testing your car counting algorithm\model, not the exact estimated parameters or templates. To have a good performance estimate, your out-of-sample guys (the holdout) must be independent of your sample. If you separate pixels instead of images, you will have some form of dependence between pixel areas - probably a complex and hard to understand dependence.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. So you are confirming my suspicion that holding out pixels is indeed (a bit) dubious since pixels are not iid. I think in the end I will accept your comment as the answer if no other suggestions are offered.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, and cbeleites. You confirm my suspicion that leaving out pixels does not truly measure well generalisation performance. I am sorry that I can accept one answer only!